# HLSL Shader changing based on camera position (Unity Game Engine)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I’m new to shader programming and I decided to try generating a skybox in Unity using a simple gradient and some voronoi noise for the stars.

Here’s how my code looks right now:

```
Shader "Custom/Starbox"
{
    Properties
    {
        // Color gradient
        _SkyColor ("Sky Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _HorizonColor ("Horizon Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _ColorStart ("Color Start", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _ColorEnd ("Color End", Range(0, 1)) = 1

        // stars noise
        _Speed ("Speed", Range(0, 100)) = 1
        _Size ("Size", Range(0, 100)) = 4
        _TilingOffset ("Tiling Offset", Vector) = (8, 2, 0, 0)
        _Power ("Power", Range(50, 200)) = 100
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Background" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float4 _SkyColor;
            float4 _HorizonColor;
            float _ColorStart;
            float _ColorEnd;

            float _Speed;
            float _Size;
            float4 _TilingOffset;
            float _Power;

            struct MeshData
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normals: NORMAL;
                float4 uv0: TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct Interpolators
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normal : TEXCOORD1;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            Interpolators vert (MeshData v)
            {
                Interpolators o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;

                o.normal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normals);
                o.uv = v.uv0;

                return o;
            }

            float2 noise2x2(float2 p)
            {
                float x = dot(p, float2(123.4, 234.5));
                float y = dot(p, float2(345.6, 456.7));
                float2 noise = float2(x, y);
                noise = sin(noise);
                noise = noise * 43748.5453;
                noise = frac(noise);
                return noise;
            }

            float InverseLerp (float a, float b, float v)
            {
                return (v - a) / (b - a);
            }

            float4 frag (Interpolators i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Calculate UV
                float3 normalizedWorldPos = normalize(i.worldPos);
                float2 uv;
                uv.y = asin(normalizedWorldPos.y) / (0.5 * 3.14159); // Arcsine of Y
                uv.x = atan2(normalizedWorldPos.x, normalizedWorldPos.z) /(6.28318); // Arctangent2 of X and Z

                // Apply tiling and offeset
                uv = uv * _TilingOffset.xy + _TilingOffset.zw;

                // stars
                float2 uv1 = uv * _Size;
                float2 currentGridId = floor(uv1);
                float2 currentGridCoord = frac(uv1);
                currentGridCoord = currentGridCoord - 0.5;

                float pointsOnGrid = 0;
                float minDistFromPixel = 100;

                float2 cameraPos = UnityObjectToViewPos(i.vertex).xy;
                float2 screenPos = (cameraPos / cameraPos.y) * 0.5 + 0.5;
                float2 jitter = noise2x2(currentGridId + floor(screenPos));
                float2 offset = jitter * _Speed * _Time.y;

                for (float a = -1.0; a <= 1.0; a++)
                {
                    for (float b = -1.0; b <= 1.0; b++)
                    {
                        float2 adjGridCoords = float2(a, b);
                        float2 pointOnAdjGrid = adjGridCoords;

                        // Randomizing
                        float2 noise = noise2x2(currentGridId + adjGridCoords);
                        pointOnAdjGrid = adjGridCoords + sin(_Time.y * noise * _Speed) * 0.5;

                        float dist = length(currentGridCoord - pointOnAdjGrid);
                        minDistFromPixel = min(dist, minDistFromPixel);

                        pointsOnGrid += smoothstep(0.95, 0.96, 1.0 - dist);
                    }
                }

                float stars = minDistFromPixel;
                stars = saturate(stars);
                stars = 1 - stars;
                stars = pow(stars, _Power);

                // SKY
                // Blend between two colors based on the uv coordinates
                float t = saturate(InverseLerp(_ColorStart, _ColorEnd, uv.y));
                float4 skyColor = lerp(_HorizonColor, _SkyColor, t);
                
                // return skyColor + stars;
                return skyColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that the position of the stars changes every time I move the camera and I was wondering how could I solve it. I’ve been looking for answers but honestly, I’m a bit confused.

I've tried changing the way of calculating the coordinates for the voronoi noise but so far all my attempts have been useless.